# SetDate on a UIDatePicker in Count Down Timer mode

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

I am using a `UIDatePicker` in `Count Down Timer` mode for users to enter travel time:
[image]

Which I can return the time in seconds like this:

```
 @IBAction func customTimeSelected(_ sender: Any) {
     print("user selected custom time: \(customeTimePicker.countDownDuration)")
}
```

But **how do I set the `UIDatePicker` in terms of seconds?**

Heres my attempt:

```
let travelDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: TimeInterval(5400))  // hour and a half in seconds
self.customeTimePicker.setDate(travelDate, animated: false)
```

This however returns an incorrect time:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered the correct way is to use `countDownDuration` on the timer instead of `setDate`. No need for `Dates` either, just a `TimeInterval`:

`self.customeTimePicker.countDownDuration = TimeInterval(5400)`